# Add new observations to a column in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

Lets start with two data frames:

```
m1 <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:10), 100, replace = TRUE), 10)
df1 <- as.data.frame(m1)
df1
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   4  5  9  8  3  8  7  1  5   5
2   2  1 NA  6  6 NA  3  8  8   2
3  NA  5  7  2  1 10  8  6  5   7
4   8  1  1  6  8  4  5  3  5   2
5  10  4  9  9  1 NA  7  8  6   2
6   1  8 NA  6  5  7  9  9  9   3
7   1 10  2  4 NA 10  6  5  5   4
8   7  3 10  7  5  5  2  1 NA   1
9  NA NA  8 10  6  4  3 10  7   7
10  7 10  2  2  9  4 NA  1  2  10

m2 <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 2:20), 100, replace = TRUE), 10)
df2 <- as.data.frame(m2)
df2
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   5 NA NA 19 20 15  5 11  4  17
2   4 13 20 NA  9 18  7 11  5  12
3  17  3 14  4  6  2 11 16 11   7
4  14 10  9 16 NA  7 20  5  8   6
5   5 14 10 20 19 16 NA  7 NA  NA
6  12 14 14  8  3 20 15  7 15  17
7   4 15 18 12  4  2 19 13  9   8
8  14 11  4 20  5 17 NA 13 19  12
9  15  3 14 16 14 19 17  8  5  NA
10  2  2 11  2 16  4 NA 18 20  NA
```

Now, I do not want to merge both df, but only some colums.

**How can I move df2$V10 to df1$V4?**

The resulting df would be composed by 20 rows, but rows 11:20 would be filled by the 10 values of df2$V10. The remaining columns in these interval should be NA.

Comment: Did you meant `df1$V4 <- df2$V10`  Or is it `library(tibble); add_column(df1, new = df2$V10, .after = 'V4')`

Comment: No, I mean something like this: `df1$V4 <- c(df1$V4, df2$10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the 'V10' column from 'df2', create a `data.frame` and use `bind_rows` to bind the two datasets.  The other column values will be by default filled by `NA`s

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, data.frame(V4 = df2$V10))
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#1   2 10 NA  9  7 NA NA  8  1   5
#2   2  5 10 10  8  8  3  7 NA   2
#3   3  7 NA  5  4  5  2  5  7   2
#4   9  4  6  4  8  6  7  9  8   2
#5   3  6  2  3  3  6 10  5  9   5
#6   1 NA  3  7  5  4  6  3  7  10
#7   6  3  1  3  4 10  2  6 NA   7
#8   9  1  5  4  4  7  4  2  2   1
#9   3  1  6  6  1  7  7  6  6   1
#10 NA  6 10  9 10 10  6  4  3   9
#11 NA NA NA 10 NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#12 NA NA NA  3 NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#13 NA NA NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#14 NA NA NA 18 NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#15 NA NA NA 20 NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#16 NA NA NA 11 NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#17 NA NA NA 15 NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#18 NA NA NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#19 NA NA NA  3 NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#20 NA NA NA 14 NA NA NA NA NA  NA
```

---

For multiple columns, subset the dataset and set the column names of interest before doing the `bind_rows`

```
bind_rows(df1, setNames(df2[c('V10', 'V8')], c('V4', 'V2')))
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I wanted. One lask question @akrun, how can I do it to paste more than one column? Let's say I don't want only df2$V10 to go to df1$V4 (as you perfectly did), but also df2$V8 to df1$V2? I mean, to merge only two (or more) columns. I tried this code: `bind_rows(df1, data.frame(V4 = df2$V10 && V1 = df2$V8))` with no success

Comment: @antecessor.  You can subset the columns of interest from 'df2' and set the names i.e. `setNames(df2[c('V10', 'V8')], c('V4', 'V2'))` and then do the `bind_rows`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @akrun